# I want edit_post_link() to open in a new window/tab (target="_blank")

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to make posts as easy to edit as possible. When a person clicks on "Edit Post", the default is to open in the same window. This can be frustrating, because it's a little difficult to quickly get back to the page they clicked "Edit Post" from (the blogroll).

Obviously, they could right-click > "Open Link in New Tab" (or Command-click), but I was wondering if there's a way to add `target="_blank"` to the edit_post_link(). Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the link via the `edit_post_link` filter.

Here's an example where we use a simple replace since we don't have the `class` and `url` explicitly as input arguments:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', function( $link, $post_id, $text )
{
    // Add the target attribute 
    if( false === strpos( $link, 'target=' ) )
        $link = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $link );

    return $link;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: That's a pretty awesome solution! Thank you.

I found the link-template.php file (where the `edit_post_link` function is located), and I figured out how it's put together. I decided to construct my "Edit Post" link with `get_edit_post_link()`.

`if ( $url = get_edit_post_link( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                   echo '<p class="edit-link"><a href="'.esc_url( $url ).'" class="post-edit-link" target="_blank">Edit post</a></p>';
               }`

Comment: You're welcome.Yes it's possible to construct it like that.  Another approach would be to reconstruct the link via filter to avoid the string replacements, but then we would probably have to hardcode the class. Sometimes it's also more precise to parse the HTML with  DOMDocument and add the new attribute through that setup. @ironoxidey

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [**`edit_post_link`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_post_link/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', 'wpse251460_admin_edit_post_link', 10, 3 );

function wpse251460_admin_edit_post_link( $link, $post_id, $text ) {

    if( is_admin() )
        $link = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $link );

    return $link;
}
```